# Rails model associations and destroy method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, associations, has-many-through

I need some help to solve my problem.

I'm working on a project where I develop the manager's functions of the application. My problem is related with two Destroy functions and how they related with themselves:

Simplifying, I have 3 models (Test, Application and JoinTestJob) described below in code sample.

I want the manager be able to destroy a JoinTestJob's object only if this is related with any Application's objects. I need consistency in Application's objects. That is the reason I created a before_destroy method in JoinTestJob model. Until here is working fine.

I also want the manager be able to destroy a Test's object, and with that, the associated objects should be destroy too, as declared in Test model. So here start the problem:

When I delete a Test's object I can see in log that all Application's objects associated are deleted first. After that, should be JoinTestJob's objects to be deleted, but I got a rollback. I know the reason of the rollback is the before_destroy method in JoinTestJob (I can see it in log). Apparently, this method still can find Application's objects, even though I saw in log that they were deleted. In this case, it seems they really would be deleted after the transaction is done.

So, how can I accomplish to having those two features working?

**Model**:

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :applications, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :persons, through: :applications

  has_many :join_test_jobs, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_many :jobs, through: :join_test_jobs

class Application < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :join_test_job
  belongs_to :person

class JoinTestJob < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :test
  belongs_to :job

  before_destroy :check_relation_between_application_and_join_test_job

  def check_relation_between_application_and_join_test_job
      if Application.find_by(join_test_job_id: "#{self.id}")
        self.errors.add(:base, "It's not possible to delete this item, because there are some applications related with. Please, delete them first.")
        throw(:abort) 
      end
  end
```

**Edit 1:**

About the log requested in comments, it's really basic. I will ask to you guys ignore some details in the image. I had to translate the problem to English, so there are some Portuguese words in the image. What is important to observe in the log:

All Application's objects related to Test are deleted first. Then, when rails started to look up for JoinTestJob's objects you can see the rollback. Before the rollback, there is a last request from Application trigged by the before_destroy method, as you can see in Log's image. The throw(:abort) method is called in this last request.

Word's Translation:

```
Application/applications => Inscricao/inscricaos

JoinTestJob/join_test_jobs => JoinConcursoCargo/join_concurso_cargos
```

To clarify things, DadosPessoalCandidato and DadosPortadorDeficiencia are models associated with Application and they hold personal informations about who is applying for, like address and phone. They can be ignored.

[image: Log img]

**Edit 2:**

Adding more information about what represent the models, so you guys can understand the problem better.

**Test model**: It's like a Civil service exam, where people would apply for getting a job. Who gets the best score in the exam would be selected for the job. This model hold information as: when this exam will happen, documents related with the exam's rules, when the result of the exam will be release and etc.

**JoinTestJob model**: It joins the concept of a Job and the Test that are offering these jobs. Here, we could find information as: specificity of the job, like the period of work, how much hours of work per day, salary and etc.

**Application model**: This model hold information related with the person who is applying for the job and the Test that are offering the job. So, we could find here information as: what job the person apply for, how much he/she payed for applying, the date of the Test (exam) will be happening, personal informations as age, name, address. A person could apply for more than one job for the same Test.

I hope I can help you guys with these new informations.

Comment: Could you add the logs to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your models:

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :applications, :dependent => :destroy

class Application < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :join_test_job, dependent: :destroy

class JoinTestJob < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :application
  validates :application, presence: true
```

so, if a Test is destroyed, then `applications` relates with `destroyed test` will be destroyed, and then JoinTestJob relates with `destroyed applications` are also destroyed.

I assume `JoinTestJob` model is stored in `join_test_jobs` model and have `application_id`.

You can make field store `application_id` is `NOT NULL` at Database level, and add `validates :application, presence: true` code make sure that a `JoinTestJob` always has one related application.

Comment: I edit my answer, so you can understand a little more. Your answer is good but it didn't apply for my case. I should wrote more information in the first time. Sorry.